# Mercurial best way to get summary of incoming file changes

Tags: mercurial

I've been trying to work out if there is a way to get the same info as hg status for incoming. (This is using hg version 1.9.2)

So if you pull a repo you can then get a summary of all the changes:

```
hg pull
hg status --rev .:default
```

However with incoming before pull the best available is:

```
hg incoming --stat
```

Which is fine for showing the files that have changed. But does not give a overall summary of all the changesets.

Now I can get close using some bash to summarise all files:

```
hg in --rev default --template '< {desc|tabindent}\n' -q | sed 's%\t%<   %'
filechanges=`hg in --rev default --template '{files} ' -q`
echo ${filechanges} | xargs -n1 | sort -u | sed -e 's%^%. %'
```

Now I can show "add,del,modify" by using a style I have created based on default ~/hgtemplates/map-cmdline.files:

```
# specify a changeset
changeset_verbose = 'changeset: {node} {rev} {branch}\ndescription:\n{desc|tabindent}\nFiles:\n{file_mods}{file_adds}{file_dels}{file_copies_switch}\n'
changeset = 'desc: {desc|tabindent}\nFiles:\n{file_mods}{file_adds}{file_dels}{file_copies_switch}\n'
changeset_quiet = '{file_mods}{file_adds}{file_dels}{file_copies_switch}\n'

# Using hg status prefixes

# Modified M prefix
start_file_mods = ''
file_mod = 'M {file_mod}\n'
end_file_mods = ''

# Added A prefix
start_file_adds = ''
file_add = 'A {file_add}\n'
end_file_adds = ''

# Deleted ! prefix
start_file_dels = ''
file_del = '! {file_del}\n'
end_file_dels = ''

# Copies C prefix ??????
start_file_copies = 'copies:     '
file_copy = 'C {name} ({source})\n'
end_file_copies = ''
```

Then use it by:

```
hg in --style ~/hgtemplates/map-cmdline.files -q
```

But then the I would have to use a more complex merge script, probably perl hashes based on name.

So is there a way with extensions or the template to do this?

Any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to understand that `hg incoming` sends the same data over the wire as `hg pull`. This is wasteful in a number of cases (where you just want to view the log), but it's nice when you need the extra information.

So, what you can do is avail yourself of the `--bundle` option to store the pull data in a temporary place, then use the bundle as a read-only overlay repository.

The following should be able to do what you need:

```
hg incoming --bundle .hg/changes.hg
hg status -R .hg/changes.hg --rev 'bundle()'
```

Plus, of course any other read-only repository operations that you may want to perform with `hg -R .hg/changes.hg`. The revset `bundle()` will contain all the incoming revisions. And note that while I am following you in using `--rev` here, you may actually want the `--change` option instead, I think.

And, once satisfied, you don't have to pull the changes over the network again, but can grab them straight from the bundle:

```
hg pull .hg/changes.hg
```

Note that you can put the bundle file wherever you want, it doesn't have to be `.hg/changes.hg`.

Comment: Pity the incoming is not cached to a standard file under .hg. 
I'm probably being paranoid trying not to pull which is probably the normal way. Like the bundle idea though.

Comment: I think --change just shows a single change, hg st --rev .:default shows the overall file changes across several. Probably should have added an example, but it was getting long winded enough.